# the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef in function

Tags: scala

I want to write an Algorithm to reverse number in scala

I have no background

```
object Main {

  def main(args : Array[String]){
    println(reverse(-136))
  }

  //Par defaut les paramètres d'une fonction scala sont immutables
  def reverse(x : Int):Int={
    var x1:Int = Math.abs(x)
    var rev:Int = 0;

    while (x1 > 0){
      var pop:Int  = x1 % 10
      x1 /=10
      if(rev > Int.MaxValue/10 || ((rev eq Int.MaxValue/ 10) && pop > 7)) 0.##
      if (rev < Int.MinValue / 10 || ((rev eq Int.MinValue  / 10) && pop < -8)) 0.##
      rev = (rev * 10) + pop
    }
    if (x < 0) rev *= -1
    return rev
  }
}
```

> Error:(15, 58) the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
>
> ```
>    if(rev > Int.MaxValue/10 || ((rev eq Int.MaxValue/ 10) && pop > 7)) 0.##
> ```

Comment: What does `0.##` mean ?

Comment: It's return an Int value in scala

Comment: Also I'd like to let you know that `.##` does not return the `Int` value in Scala, it is a way to call `.hashCode` as can be seen in the [docs for Any](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Any.html###():Int) and in current implementation `Integer.hashCode` returns the value but it is an implementation detail you should not rely on. Scala does support an explicit `return` but its usage is discouraged and a more idiomatic way is to use a tail recursion instead. As of now those 2 `if`s doe nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`eq` is a pointer comparison operator in *Scala*, and therefore is used to compare values of type `AnyRef`. But you're comparing integer values, and `Int`s are derived from `AnyVal`, not `AnyRef`.

To compare `Int` quantities for equality (or anything else in *Scala* for equality, for that matter), use the `==` operator instead.

Incidentally, neither of your `if` statements affects the result, since you are not changing anything and discarding the result. (And, as other's have commented, `0.##` is equivalent to `0.hashCode`, which just happens to have the value 0 for an `Int` value of 0. I can't imagine that that's what you actually require.)

**UPDATE** A *functional* version of your code would look like this:

```scala
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.util.Try

// By extending from the App trait, we do not need a main function.
object Main
extends App {

  println(reverse(-136))

  // Return a decimal number with the digits in x reversed. If an error occurs (such as an
  // overflow), then the exception will be returned wrapped in a Failure instance.
  // If it succeeds, the result is wrapped in a Success.
  def reverse(x: Int): Try[Int] = {

    // If x is negative, we need to subtract values; if positive, we need to add them. In
    // both cases, we need to trap integer overflows. Math.subtractExact does the former,
    // Math.addExact does the latter.
    //
    // If an overflow occurs, an ArithmeticException will be thrown.
    val op: (Int, Int) => Int = if(x < 0) Math.subtractExact else Math.addExact

    // Process the next digit.
    //
    // Note: this function will throw an exception if an overflow occurs (of type
    // ArithmeticException).
    @tailrec
    def nextDigit(value: Int, result: Int): Int = {

      // If value is now 0, then return the result.
      if(value == 0) result

      // Otherwise, process the right-most digit of value into a new result.
      else {

        // Take the right-most digit of value (removing the sign).
        val digit = Math.abs(value % 10)

        // Perform the next iteration, updating value and result in the process.
        //
        // Note: The result is updated according to the "op" we defined above.
        nextDigit(value / 10, op(Math.multiplyExact(result, 10), digit))
      }
    }

    // Perform the conversion by looking at the first digit. Convert any thrown exceptions
    // to failures.
    Try(nextDigit(x, 0))
  }
}
```

Some points to note:

1. There are no `var` declarations, nor are there any `while` loops. (These are symptoms of *procedural programming*, whereas *Scala* encourages *functional programming* as an alternative.) The `while` loop is replaced by a *tail-recursive* function. (`@tailrec` tells the *Scala* compiler that `nextDigit` must be tail-recursive; if it isn't, the compiler will issue a compile-time error.) The `var` declarations are replaced by arguments to this recursive function.
2. The `reverse` function is fully defined. It doesn't throw exceptions (any exceptions thrown by `nextDigit` are handled and not passed to the caller), and returns a result for every value of `x` that is provided; for those values that cannot be reversed (because they overflow a 32 integer result, for example), a `Failure` instance is returned instead.
3. There are no `return` statements; use of `return` is considered poor style in *Scala*, given it's functional nature.

If you have any questions about this, add a comment and I'll attempt to answer it.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the `Int` into a `String`, which is easy to reverse, and then change it back again, but you have to test for the `-` character.

```
x.toString.reverse.foldLeft(0)((n,c) => if (c=='-') -1*n else n*10 + c.asDigit)
```

If you'd prefer to keep it all in the field of numbers...

```
Stream.iterate(x)(_/10)       //an infinite reduction of the original number
      .takeWhile(_ != 0)      //no longer infinite
      .map(_ % 10)            //reduce to single digits
      .foldLeft(0)(_*10 + _)  //fold all the digits back into an Int
```